# Django permissions to view

Tags: django, django-views, django-permissions

I want to restrict access to certain views based on the current User's email address. Are Permissions the way to go here? My thought is "no" because, as far as I understand, permissions are for model objects.

Comment: you can always create your own view decorator...

Comment: Sure, why not? That way  you can assign that permission to that specific user object..

Comment: If I do it that way the only way I could use `user.has_perm` would be if I created my own authentication backend which isn't the end of the world.

Comment: Probably you can use different groups for different email ids and then use simple if else conditions in your template to redirect the users accordingly.